# Why my Front-End requests are all sended to Back-End project?

Tags: vue.js, frontend

I'm learning about front-end and back-end interfaces docking. But I met a problem.

---

My back-end project's port is **8081** and when I send this request `http://localhost:8081/hello`, I will receive a reponse body`hello`

And my front-end project's port is **8080**. When I send request likes `http://localhost:8080/hello`, the response of it is the same as `http://localhost:8081/hello`

---

Here's my `vue.config.js`

```
let proxyObj = {};

proxyObj['/']={
    ws: false,
    target: 'http://localhost:8081',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/': ''
    }
}

module.exports= {
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8080,
        proxy: proxyObj
    }
}
```

If I change `proxy: proxyObj` to `proxy: null` then go `http://localhost:8080/hello`, I receive nothing but a blank. Is anything wrong with my `vue.config.js` file?

---

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevServer proxy will proxy requests  depend on your proxy config:

```js
// '/'means this rule will match all requests
proxyObj['/']={
  ws: false,
  // target means requests that matched will be sent to http://localhost:8081
  target: 'http://localhost:8081',
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
      '^/': ''
  }
}
```

With this config, all your requests will be sent to the backend server, you will receive a response from the server. If you set your config object to null, your requests will be sent to your frontend project: http://localhost:8080, so you can't receive any response.

---

See [here](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#core-concept) for more detail about proxy config.

Comment: Thx! But I copied these codes from course video, but my teacher can visit front-end pages with ```http://localhost:8080/#/```, but I can't visit with the same url, response's status is 200 but page is blank.